# Is it bad practice to use a method's return as a parameter in java?

Tags: java

Is it considered bad practice to use a method that returns an object as a parameter? I have the following method:

```
public static boolean checkForBlanks(PageDescription pageDesc){
    // do some stuff
}
```

And this method is called within another method:

```
checkForBlanks(aPage.getPageDescription());
```

Is it better practice to create a `PageDescription` object using the `getPageDescription` method first, then pass that as a parameter(The `checkForBlanks` methods will check a number of fields on this object) or is there any advantage to be had with the current implementation?

The `PageDescription` object is not used anywhere else in the calling method, so it is used explicitly in the `checkForBlanks` method only.

Comment: In this case what you have is good.  Creating a page description object would needlessly clutter the code.  If you were going to be doing more things with the object later then at that point it would make sense to have its own reference to it.

Comment: Also mind, that a dedicated variable may improve the readability of your code, if the method has a bad/an ambiguous name (for example in a third party API). Then a good variable makes it easier to understand what the method returns. In your case here, where the methods purpose is clear, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the instance returned by `aPage.getPageDescription()` is only used once within your method, there is no advantage in assigning `aPage.getPageDescription()` to a variable prior to passing it to `checkForBlanks()`.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases it is simply a matter of preference. I don't like the concept of tieing the hands behind the back in order to fit some misguided concept of code.

In general I prefer the idea of good looking code is good.

`checkStuff(storage.getEntry());` is a easy line of good that is clear and everyone can easily follow it.

`World.getSomething().doStuff(Storages.getStorage(key).getEntry());` is for example less clear to read.

Keep it clean and simple. That is the best way to go by it. If you look a week later at your code and have no clue what the heck you did, then you did something wrong.

Good code is in the end:
[image]

Have fun coding.

Answer (score 0):

you should go with this (good);

```
checkForBlanks(aPage.getPageDescription());
```

instead of this (bad):

```
PageDescription pageDescription = aPage.getPageDescription();
checkForBlanks(pageDescription);
```

`pageDescription` in the second variant is an unnecessary local variable because there is no value read from afterwards. So you blow up your code (okay, just one line), and it will cost CPU time and Memory consumption for creating the object. Both is not needed.

Comment: A very minor point.  It would likely only cost more performance at compile time because the compiler would probably inline it.